# Подбор пароля

Tags: php, пароль, хеширование, шифрование

Доброго времени суток, форумчане.

Есть функция `crypt()`, с помощью которого шифровался пароль. Есть соль, которая использовалась при шифровании, и, собственно, сам хэш, полученный в результате работы функции `crypt()`.
Задача - подобрать пароль так, чтоб хэши совпали. Метод посимвольного подбора (a-zA-Z0-9) не самый лучший, так как страница просто перестаёт отвечать. Подбор прекращается на пароле 'zl'. Точнее, как когда, иногда на 'zB'. В общем, прекращается на 'z*'. Хотя был установлен `set_time_limit(0);`, всё равно прекращается подбор.

Какие будут варианты? Не обязательно на php, главное подобрать пароль. Заранее благодарю за помощь.

P.S.: Лучший ответ будет награждён лайком и отметкой 'Правильный'. ;)

Comment: @sergiks, за идею спасибо, но что делать, если я использую обычный хостинг, где нет доступа к командной строке? Поставить лампу на свой линукс и запустить оттуда? Но не будет ли уменьшение скорости подбора за счёт более слабого оборудования? AMD A8-3870 и 4Гб оперативы - это не серверное железо всё-таки... И в таком случае можно ли задействовать мощность видео-ядра? Насколько я знаю, оно может значительно ускорить процесс. Если да, то как это сделать на линуксе?

Comment: @intro94, а Вы для начала протестируйте (померьте время одних и тех же вычислений) хостинг-сервер и свой AMD.

Вполне возможно, что хостер предоставляет виртуалку (делит он реальное железо для десятков пользователей) и Вы  приятно (или неприятно?) удивитесь, увидев что сервер не так уж и быстр.

Comment: @avp, Вы абсолютно правы. У меня даже не виртуальный сервер, а обычный хостинг. Просто я как-то не думал, что хостинг настолько плох может быть. Ну да ладно, завтра уже с компа протестирую р отвечу.

Пока что всем спасибо. :)

Comment: @sergiks спасибо, ваш совет помог. Запустил скрипт из под терминала CentOS-а, и проблем с временем работы нет. 

Переведите свой ответ в комментарий, я его отмечу как правильный. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выполняйте скрипт не через веб, а прямо из командной строки - не будет ограничений по времени.